# How to load html+js into mshtml/webbrowser control and deploy as single exe?

Tags: c++, mshtml

I'm new to c++ windows programming, I know and saw applications (ebook exe kind of apps) that takes html+js+css and such and converting it to single self contained exe.

My question is how they do that in c++?

Comment: I think you might be referring to Windows Script Host ([HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)).

Comment: this is not what im looking for

Comment: You can use [res:// protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28VS.85%29.aspx).